# Puppet master receiving a YAML error after upgrade to 2.7.25-2

Tags: puppet, phusion-passenger, ruby, rhel6, puppetmaster

Our `puppetmaster` server was upgraded to the latest available on RHEL6 (`puppet-2.7.25-2.el6.noarch`). We are now receiving errors such as this on the master:

```
Aug 26 11:36:59 master1 puppet-master[5555]: Could not intern from yaml: instance of IO needed
```

And this on the client running 0.25.6 on RHEL4:

```
Aug 26 11:36:59 foo1 Puppet (err): Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not intern from yaml: instance of IO needed
```

The server is running using Apache and passenger which I'm not familiar with. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

### Update

Per @FelixFrank, after stopping `httpd` service, ran the following:

```
$ sudo puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose --trace
```

This provided me with the following traceback after a puppet client attempts to retrieve its catalog:

```
err: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:176:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:176:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml.rb:201:in `safe_load'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml.rb:141:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/formats.rb:6:in `intern'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/format_handler.rb:12:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/format_handler.rb:12:in `protect'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/format_handler.rb:26:in `intern'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/format_handler.rb:108:in `convert_from'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:25:in `extract_facts_from_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:38:in `find'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:195:in `find'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/handler.rb:111:in `do_find'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/handler.rb:68:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/handler.rb:68:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick/rest.rb:24:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:45:in `listen'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:42:in `listen'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:41:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:41:in `listen'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:38:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/http/webrick.rb:38:in `listen'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/server.rb:126:in `listen'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/network/server.rb:141:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/daemon.rb:124:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/master.rb:202:in `main'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application/master.rb:146:in `run_command'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:309:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:416:in `hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:309:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:407:in `exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:309:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:69:in `execute'
/usr/bin/puppet:4
err: Could not intern from yaml: instance of IO needed
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: Are both agent and master updated? - To debug this, please stop the master and start a debugging session using `puppet master --nodaemonize --verbose --trace`. The error should appear along with a call trace once the agent checks in.

Comment: @FelixFrank how can I accomplish this when puppetmaster is running via Passenger?

Comment: Stop `apache`, then run the standalone master as described above. It should just work. Make sure it listens on the same port that your passenger vhost usually does. (Use `--masterport` if that's an issue.)

Comment: That looks like the puppet from EPEL (which is ancient) rather than the one from puppetlabs (which is current). Do you specifically need to be this far out of date? Puppet Labs doesn't support 2.7 anymore.

Comment: The concern is that we can't get an agent more current than 0.25.6 running on RHEL4. We have seen issues before when connecting those clients to 3.x puppet masters.

Comment: Good luck. [RHEL 4 is on extended life support](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/) and it's past time for migration plans for such boxes. I think Puppet Enterprise has a puppet agent build for EL4, though, if you want to go down that road.

Comment: There have been quite a few ruby/puppet/rails CVE's regarding yaml vulnerabilities. I'm guessing that puppet 2.7 won't parse the older yaml due to the security fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Puppet changelog](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/release_notes.html), 2.7.22 included changes on how YAML was being processed:

> A critical vulnerability was found in puppet wherein it was possible for the puppet master to take YAML from an untrusted client
>   via the REST API. This YAML could be deserialized to construct an
>   object containing arbitrary code.

This was due to a [security vulnerability](http://puppetlabs.com/security/cve/cve-2013-3567). To temporarily mitigate the issue, I downgraded to an earlier version from PuppetLabs' repo and locked the `puppet-server` package via `yum versionlock`.